# Is it possible/supported to do an Impala query with Java?

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, jsch, impala

I want to run an impala query in java on an HBase table. I couldn't find a way to do this though.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to a library or an example or anything where I can run the query, and get the results?

I have already tried using jsch to just run the command on the server, but unfortunately that's giving me issues (no output is appearing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't really used it but looks like https://github.com/pauldeschacht/impala-java-client might meet your needs

Comment: Seems like it'd be perfect. I'm having a little bit of issues with testing it out (mainly invalid method names), but I'll keep looking into it! Thanks. I don't supposed you know of an api anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Cloudera ships an Impala JDBC Connector, check the [docs](http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/documentation/enterprise/5-2-x/topics/impala_jdbc.html).